# Creating a Custom Map Editor using XNA and Windows Forms

Tags: xna

I'm looking to create my own level editor for a game I'm making, and I came across the following post:

[Tutorial or Example of creating custom sprite tool/map editor for XNA?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28507/tutorial-or-example-of-creating-custom-sprite-tool-map-editor-for-xna)

In the example posted by Blau, I am unsure what needs to be replaced in this line, and with what:

```
XnaControlGame.CreateAndShow<MainDialog, VoxelEditorGame>( );
```

If anyone could help at all, that would be great!

Comment: I do wish people would stop using, posting and endorsing these awful hacks for XNA + WinForms. Please, please, please use the [official WinForms sample code](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1).

Comment: @AndrewRussell Seems your link is kinda "dead" now. Any way to still get to the original article on MSDN?

Comment: To answer my own question, [this is the correct link now](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MainDialog is the type of your windows main form, that needs to implement `IXnaFormContainer`

```
//Form1 is the standard winform when a new WindowsForms application is created
public partial Form1 : Form, IXnaFormContainer{

//YourControl is some control placed on your form. I'm guessing a Panel will work
public Control XnaControl { get{return this.YourControl} }

//Game1 is your XNA game class
private XnaControlGame _game;
public XnaControlGame Game { get{return _game;} set{_game=value;} }
}
```

In the next step you need to alter your `Game1` class

```
public class Game1 : XnaControlGame{  //instead of Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
  public Game1 ( IntPtr handle, System.Windows.Forms.Form parentForm, System.Windows.Forms.Control surfaceControl) : base(handle, parentForm, surfaceControl){
    ...
  }
}
```

In the static void main

```
static void Main(string[] args){
  XnaControlGame.CreateAndShow<Form1, Game1>( );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This clears things up a bit, but I'm still having some issues.  When I go to run the code, I receive the following error:

`'WindowsGame3.Form1' does not implement interface member 'WindowsGame3.IXnaFormContainer.Game'`

and this error:

`'WindowsGame3.Form1' does not implement interface member 'WindowsGame3.IXnaFormContainer.XnaControl'`

I'm not exactly sure what to make of this.

Comment: It sounds like you are implementing the interface, but have not provided the two methods required like in the first code box. `XnaControl` and `Game`

Comment: So `XnaControl` and `Game` need to be in the Form1.cs file correct?  Also, what exactly am I returning with `return this.YourControl`?  I apologize if this is something obvious, but I don't have much experience with WinForms at all at the moment.

Comment: `XnaControl` and `Game` are Properties of your Form, that is correct. With `return this.YourControl` you are returning the control that xna will render to. Make a Panel, name it YourControl and add it to the Form (via Designer or code). Don't forget to let your Game1 inherit from `XnaControlGame`.

Comment: I'm getting closer here!  My one and only error I have left now is:

`Error 1 'WindowsGame3.Form1' does not implement interface member 'WindowsGame3.IXnaFormContainer.Game'. 'WindowsGame3.Form1.Game' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.`

Thank you again for all your help and patience!

Comment: try **public** `XnaControlGame Game { get{return _game;} set{_game=value;} }`

Comment: Now I'm left with the following:

`Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'WindowsGame3.XnaControlGame' to 'WindowsGame3.Game1'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` and `Error 1 'WindowsGame3.XnaControlGame' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`

Comment: Error 2: use `private XnaControlGame _game`
Error 1: you need `public Game1(){ ... ` constructor, instead of the one you are currently using.

Comment: Currently I'm just using the default Game class:

`    public class Game1 : XnaControlGame
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }...`

I feel like an idiot, but where do I need to make the changes?

Comment: That looks correct. are you calling `new XnaControlGame` somewhere? If so, you need to use `XnaControlGame.CreateAndShow<Form1, Game1>( );` instead

Comment: I am not calling `new XnaControlGame` anywhere.  EDIT: it might be worth mentioning that the error is on the line with `public Game1()'

Comment: I've edited the constructor in code #2. That should do it. Be sure to look at the `XnaControlGame` constructor, as it already defines `graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager( this );` and more.

Comment: So in the game class, I should remove `public Game1()` and replace it with the edit in code #2?  Also, what should be contained within the `XnaControlGame` in code #2?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake its a constructor for Game1. I've edited the code. Use the constructor as before.

Comment: Thank you!  You're absolutely amazing!  Everything is working now :).

Answer (score 4):

This might not be what you want, but you're using an unofficial workaround to do this. I would honestly reccomend doing it the offical way with a UserControl, then you can even design inside the WinForms designer!

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1

Comment: They seem to be doing the same, so I wouldn't call it a workaround. The msdn example is more straight forward and complete though. It would have to be changed to be able to accommodate the game class.

Comment: It's definitely a workaround as it directly hacks the game into the control. There's no doubt you want to use the official sample on this one. (No knock on you, you answered his question.)

Comment: I only glossed briefly over the code, but the msdn example uses the handle of a (user defined) control to draw to it. The *workaround* sets the handle globally for the device, which in the end I assume does the exact same thing. I do however agree actually, since the msdn example is more complete as it handles lost devices, multiple controls and such (Don't worry :))